# detect if flash is installed without js

Tags: java, javascript, flash

If flash is not installed, i want to replace the flash animation with a jquery animation.
BUT if flash and js are not installed, i want to display a div with a message to the user.
how is it possible to check if flash is not running at the clientside without using js?

kind regards,

Answer (score 3):

Use a javascript event to replace your  message with the Flash animation. If Javascript is not running, you will see the message instead.

[SWFObject](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/) is a great little tool for completing exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Add to HTML body classes: "no_flash no_js". They will be your default when js & flash not available.

Then when you have js, with it's help remove no_js class.
With help of js try to determine flash and if it's present, show flash else -- js animation.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way around:

1. Display a div with a message
2. If JavaScript is on, replace the div with either:

   a) a Flash animation, if Flash is installed or

   b) a jQuery based animation